# How to quit iTunes when copy of it has expired?

Tags: mac, itunes

I was enjoying iTunes until today when it expired.

Then I downloaded the latest iTunes from Apple's site and started its installation.

During installation it is giving me this message:

> "Please quit iTunes before continuing
>   with this update...".

but in iTunes menu option to quit is disabled.

Can any one suggest how to quit an expired copy of iTunes or how to upgrade it so that I can continue enjoying it?

Thanks,

Devarshi

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have an open dialog window in iTunes, preventing you from closing it.

On the Dock, just right click on the iTunes icon and click "Quit", or use the `Force Quit` option from holding down `Command`, `Option` and `Escape`.

Comment: thanx..... it worked :)